# Skrollr Image Flicker. Firefox preload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload, skrollr

Im in the process of developing a 'flipbook-style' animation using Skrollr by triggering background image changes when the user scrolls to indicated positions on the page. The issue i'm having is that in browser the image changes are delayed, creating what can only be defined as a 'flicker' of white between the frames.

```
<div class="section" style="background: url('frame1.png')"
data-560-top="background-image:!url('frame1.png');" 
data-440-top="background-image:!url('frame2.png');">
```

The HTML is simple; it basically states that at 560 pixels from the top of the div (in relation to the browser window), the background should be at frame 1, then as the user scrolls closer to the div (440 pixels from the top of the div) the background image changes to frame 2. I plan to use up to around 20 frames and the images are quite large.

I have created a [JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/diviza/1/edit?html,js,output) which includes a very simplified sample with images from placehold.it. This includes the Skrollr script and an example layout of a section of my project. The key difference being that the images in my project are of much larger scale.

```html
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery.preLoadImages(
    'http://www.placehold.it/300x200.png',
    'http://www.placehold.it/300x200.png'
);
```

The above snippet seems to be working on Chrome, however the flicker issue remains in Firefox. Based on research, firefox handles cached images differently from Chrome? (e.g Where an image is not considered needed by firefox at a given time, it is trashed?)

I would like to know how I could possibly force all browsers to preload the images efficiently, to potentially avoid the background image flicker upon change. I am still quite new to Javascript/JQuery.

I hope I have provided a clear explanation. All assistance appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

You can preload images using CSS only, no need for JS.  Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/) for more info.  Another interesting way to do it is in the comment section of the article.  Basically you assign the background image to a pseudo-element so that is is cached and ready to be used whenever.  See this code for an example:

```
#something:before {
     content: url("./img.jpg");
     width:0;
     height:0;
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this seems like an effective method where only one image is required to be cached, but in order to cache so many large images, this method would require creating a large number of pseudoelements. Someone recently has suggested using one image sprite sheet containing all of the frames but this has come with its own issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100087/skrollr-background-position-with-css-steps. Thanks for the suggestion though :)